# How to force scroll when element height is not enough

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div element (with id `target`) with several anchors in it that have ids. I have a button connected to a javascript function via `onclick` property that lets the div element scroll so that a certain anchor appears at the top position within the div. The function is something like this:

```
scrollToTag = function(id){
    var target = document.getElementById('target');
    var goal = document.getElementById(id);
    target.scrollTop = goal.offsetTop - target.offsetTop;
};
```

When the height of the div (`target`) is not enough, the goal anchor does not go to the top of the div because it cannot scroll any further.

What is the best way to force it to scroll? I came up with an idea of appending a blank element with height of the div the the div itself, but I am not sure it that is good. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: You could use an `overflow:auto` wrapper, and set `margin-bottom: 100%` to the `target`.

Comment: @Teemu This has difficulty with scrolling.

Comment: I can't imagine what that would be (similar styling has worked for me), but it seems you've got a great solution already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few different ways depending on your exact situation but I would recommend the [`:after` pseudo element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after):

```
#target:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 100%
}
```

There is no extra markup and it forces there to be the gap at the bottom that you mentioned in your question.